# Lines intersections with a point in 1D

Tags: algorithms

I have an array of lines in 1D represented by coordination and weight, it can be only positive weight. I want to find all the lines that intersect a point in a given range.

Is there any efficient way of doing it?

Comment: from line in 1D, do you mean for a line you store [start,end] like [2,4] ?

Comment: @AshishNegi [start,weight] like [9,4]

Comment: what do you mean by weight ? is it like end = start + weight ?

Comment: @AshishNegi yes

Comment: Interval trees should do that for you.

Comment: sort lines by the ascending ends and then then filtering them by "start and end of the range" by binary search. would give you the lines that are in the range. after that you can find if they are intersecting or not.

Comment: your full answer is on wikipedia. Also, there are many lecture notes about interval stabbing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the trivial scan in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time where $n$ is the number of intervals (just check for each interval whether your value is in it) or you can use an interval tree; those allow for querying in logarithmic time, see for example [here](http://www.dgp.utoronto.ca/people/JamesStewart/378notes/22intervals/).

Answer (score 3):

If you store all of the intervals in a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree), then the operation "find all intervals that contain the point $x$" is known as a stabbing query.  Building a segment tree from $n$ intervals takes $O(n \lg n)$ time, but once it is built, you can answer a stabbing query in $O(\lg n + k)$ time, where $k$ is the number of intervals that intersect the point $x$ (i.e., the length of the output of the operation).

In comparison, a linear scan (as described in G. Bach's answer) requires no preprocessing but takes $O(n)$ time to answer each stabbing query.  Thus, if you plan to make many stabbing queries on the same set of intervals, it may be faster to build a segment tree in advance, as each stabbing query can then be answered much faster.

See also [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), which have similar properties.